# Visual Studio 2013 spacing between lines in editor

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I've recently been using VS2013 and I've noticed that there is spacing between lines after brackets. The link below is a screenshot:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfyhL.png]

This has been bothering me for a while now and I can't seem to find a solution for it. Has anyone else been bothered by this and found a way to turn it off?